# Generating a list of combinations with repetition... with a twist

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am trying to generate every combination of a dynamic character set `CHAR_LIST`, within the range of `lower` and `upper`. The code I have pasted below works, but I feel it is horribly inefficient and I would like to make it as fast as possible.

For example, if I want to generate a list between "aab" and "zzz" with only lowercase alphabetic characters it would output: `['aab', 'aac', 'aad', ..., 'zzy', 'zzz']`

If there is anything I have left unclear please leave a comment and I will clarify. Thanks!

What I have working right now.

```
def generate_list(lower, upper):
    result = [lower]
    while lower != upper:
        if CHAR_LIST.index(lower[len(lower)-1:len(lower)]) + 1 < len(CHAR_LIST):
            lower = lower[:len(lower)-1] + CHAR_LIST[CHAR_LIST.index(lower[len(lower)-1:len(lower)]) + 1]
        else:
            new_lower = ""
            new_dig = 0
            inc_next = True
            for i in lower[::-1]:
                if i == CHAR_LIST[len(CHAR_LIST)-1] and inc_next:
                    new_lower += CHAR_LIST[0]
                    new_dig += 1
                else:
                    if inc_next:
                        inc_next = False
                        new_lower += CHAR_LIST[CHAR_LIST.index(i) + 1]
                    else:
                        new_lower += i
            if new_dig == len(lower):
                lower = str(CHAR_LIST[0])*int(len(lower)+1)
            else:
                lower = new_lower[::-1]
        result.append(lower)
    return result
```

EDIT: I forgot to add, as this is part of the challenge, that it must also compute a list that has different lengths for start and end points. For example it must compute the list between "a" and "zzz" also. Sorry for the late revision, and thanks for the creative answers so far :)

Comment: About your edited in requirement: are the lower and upper values boundaries on the alphabet, with repetition indicating a number of digits, or are they specific values (like a range of integers from `3` to `555`? that is, would a sequence from `b` to `cc` be `["b", "c", "d", "bb", "bc", "bd", "cb", "cc"]` or `["b", "c", "d", "e", ... "z", "aa", ..., "bz", "ca", "cb", "cc"]`? Can either boundary be somethign other than a repetition of the same character (e.g. `xyz`)?

Comment: The `CHAR_LIST` is arbitrary, so either must be possible if the list is defined as such. The characters might not be in any evident order either, which means it needs to reference the list to see what character comes next incrementally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me quite a while to understand how your code worked, because you're doing a lot more work than you need to. Here's an aggressively "pythonized" version of the same algorithm, which I suspect will quite a bit faster than what you have now:

```
def generate_strings(value, bound, alpha):
    yield value
    while value != bound: # run until we have reached bound
        for i, c in enumerate(reversed(value)): # loop over the string in reverse
            if c != alpha[-1]: # can this character be incremented?
                # construct an incremented value
                value = value[:-1-i] + alpha[alpha.index(c)+1] + alpha[0]*i
                break # exit the for loop
        else: # run only if for loop ended without breaking
            value = alpha[0]*(len(value) + 1) # make a longer string
        yield value
```

The function is a generator, so if you want a list result, pass it to the list constructor, as in this example output:

```
>>> print(list(generate_strings("b", "cc", "abcd")))
['b', 'c', 'd', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

I made the sequence of characters an argument to the function, rather than using a global variable. The `bound` argument can also be `None` or some other nonsensical value to get an infinite generator (but don't pass that to `list()` without shortening it!). Here's an example of both of those features:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>>
>>> print(list(islice(generate_strings("xyzzy", None, ascii_lowercase), 5)))
['xyzzy', 'xyzzz', 'xzaaa', 'xzaab', 'xzaac']
```

There are a few things done in the code that might not be obvious if you're new to Python.

First off, I use a lot of negative indexes into the strings. This counts from the right, starting with `-1` as the rightmost character. This alone would simplify your code a lot (you had a lot of `x[len(x)-1]`).

Next, I use the `enumerate` and `reversed` built-in functions to loop over the string from right to left, keeping track of how many characters I've looped over. I think this is about what you were doing with your `i` and `new_dig` values, but I think it's much clearer. There are a lot of helpful built in generators in Python!

Finally, I used a `break` statement to exit the `for` loop early, with an `else` block to handle the case where we got to the end without `break`ing. This sort of `else` on a loop seemed useless to me when I first learned about it, but it really is handy in situations like this one, where the majority of runs of the loop will result in a `break` statement being hit.

Comment: This is why I love SO. Thanks a million for your in-depth, yet clear answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
CHAR_LIST = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

def generate_list(lower, upper):
    lower, upper = tuple(lower), tuple(upper)
    return ["".join(e) for e in itertools.product(CHAR_LIST, repeat=len(lower))
                  if e >= lower and e <= upper]

print generate_list("aab", "zzz")
```

Comment: I don't think combinations is right -- I'm not positive that you can get `zzz` from that for example.

Comment: Thanks for the note, fixed (and +1 to yours)

Comment: Yep, I think I buy this one now.  cudos for resolving the tuples for comparison up-front.  That saves a join for each element which doesn't fit in the range.  Not sure if it would be faster in the wild, but there's something elegant about it.  +1.

Comment: @mgilson: I just did a test, and found that `timeit.timeit("x > y", setup="x = ('a', 'b', 'c'); y = ('a', 'b', 'd')", number=10000000)` is about twice as fast as `timeit.timeit("''.join(x) > y", setup="x = ('a', 'b', 'c'); y = 'abd'", number=10000000)` (though if you skip the join, string comparisons are a bit faster).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `itertools.product` is what you want:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product
all_combos = (''.join(x) for x in product(ascii_lowercase,repeat=3))
filtered = (s for s in all_combos if s > 'aaa')
```

In keeping with the awesomeness of itertools, I've use generators here, but you could easily turn the second one into a list comprehension to get the list -- And I also trust that it's easy to see how you could turn that into a function with `lower` and `upper` bounds with a very simple modification to the `filtered` generator expression (the lower bound is already included ;-) ...